# Set up a result for a composite part of a mock

Tags: authentication, rhino-mocks, identity, httpcontext

We try to mock a HttpContext of an MVC 3 application using RhinoMocks
Looks like this:

```
HttpContextBase context = mocks.StrictMock<HttpContextBase>();
HttpRequestBase request = mocks.PartialMock<HttpRequestBase>();
IPrincipal user = mocks.StrictMock<IPrincipal>(); 
HttpCookieCollection cookies = new HttpCookieCollection();
IIdentity identity = mocks.StrictMock<IIdentity>();
HttpResponseBase response = mocks.PartialMock<HttpResponseBase>();

SetupResult.For(response.Cookies).Return(cookies);
SetupResult.For(context.User).Return(user);
SetupResult.For(user.Identity).Return(identity);
SetupResult.For(context.Request).Return(request);
SetupResult.For(context.Response).Return(response);
mocks.Replay(context);
```

In my test I need the user to be authenticated so I added following:

```
var identity = context.User.Identity;
mocks.BackToRecord(identity);
SetupResult.For(identity.IsAuthenticated).Return(true).Repeat.Any();
mocks.Replay(identity);
```

This however results in a 
"The result for IIdentity.get_IsAuthenticated(); has already been setup." 
exception to be thrown.

Why? What do I need to do to make the authenticated settable in my tests?

Comment: @Patrick: I see you edited my question, what is nature of your changes? I can't spot any right off.

Comment: If you click on the time link in the "edited xxx hours ago", you can view revision history (with comments).  You'll notice that I fixed the code formatting on your first code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time since I used the record/replay semantics vs. the AAA (Arrange/Act/Assert) syntax, but try doing the `SetupResult` on just the identity mock:

```
mocks.BackToRecord(identity);
SetupResult.For(identity.IsAuthenticated).Return(true).Repeat.Any();
mocks.Replay(identity);
```

**NEW ANSWER**

Get rid of the `.Repeat.Any()`.  I think since this is a property, you just need to set the return value.  Rhino.Mocks will always return that value -- you don't need to tell it to repeat.  I did a quick test and was getting the same error you got, but as soon as I removed the `.Repeat.Any()`, it worked.

Comment: Patrick thanks for your help. I updated my code to reflect your suggestion. It makes no difference however, the code still throws the exception